# Best strategy to execute tasks with high branch divergency

Tags: multithreading, cuda, simd

I have a project written a few years ago that do compute N similar tasks in a row on a single CPU core.

These N tasks are completely independent so they could be computed in parallel.

However, the problem with these tasks is that the control flow inside each task differs much from one task to other, so the SIMT approach implemented in CUDA will more likely impede than help.

I came up with an idea to launch N blocks with 1 thread in each to break the warp dependency for threads.

Can anyone suggest a better way to optimise the computations in this situation, or point out possible pitfalls with my solution.

Comment: I believe it is not possible to answer this question without any further detail. As you may know, branching is only problematic when all threads in a warp don't follow the same path through a branch. So, I would say: try to organize your tasks so that statistically all those with the same control flow follow the same path, if possible.

Comment: I thought that branching is problematic if at least one thread follow a different path than the others do, because all of them have to wait this particular thread before proceed the execution from the next common command. In worst case 32 threads in a single warp will wait for each other and execute one after the other in a row, which means 32x slowing down. Am I wrong?

Comment: You are right. Note that my comment above is not in contradiction with your own comment. I'm just saying: organize your tasks to maximize the probability that a warp follows the same path through a branch. I can't tell anything better in absence of any further information. Another thing I can suggest is to completely reformulate your problem (possibly ignoring your legacy software) by avoiding control flows, if possible. Finally, try to improve your question being more specific, mentioning the specific problem your re facing, posting an example or better a small reproducer of your bottleneck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right with your comment what causes and what is caused by divergence of threads in a warp. However, launching configuration mentioned by you (1 thread in each block) totally diminishes potential of GPU. Threads in a warp/half-warp is the maximal unit of threads that is eventually executed in parallel on a single multiprocessor. So, having one thread in the block and having 32 these blocks is actually as having 32 threads in the warp with different paths. First case is even worse because number resident blocks per multiprocessors is quite limited (8 or 16, depending on compute capability).

Therefore, if you want to fully exploit potential of GPU, keep in mind Jack's comment and try to reorganize threads so that threads of a single warp would follow equal execution path.